# Tratar array do retorno de Json com CURL

Tags: php, json

O código abaixo retorna resultados de códigos de imóveis de um API Rest, e ela vem com array dentro de array, esperava tratar a lista para conseguir apenas uma array Código com o seu valor, ex:

```
<?php
$dados = 'Codigo';

$key         =  'c9fdd79584fb8d369a6a579af1a8f681'; //Informe sua chave aqui
$postFields  =  json_encode( $dados );
$url         =  'http://sandbox-rest.vistahost.com.br/imoveis/listar?key=' . $key;
$url        .=  '&pesquisa=' . $postFields;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array( 'Accept: application/json' ) );
$result = curl_exec( $ch );

$result = json_decode( $result, true );

$totalImovel = count($result);

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $result );
echo '</pre>';
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [3152] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 3152
        )

    [3153] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 3153
        )

    [2448] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 2448
        )

    [3141] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 3141
        )

    [3151] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 3151
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 25
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 38
        )

    [3378] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 3378
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 42
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 54
        )

)
```

Como fazer esse resultado ficar como o exemplo abaixo, esse não consegui fazer:

```
{
'Codigo': 3152,
........
}
```

E tentei imprimir os resultados em um for:

```
$totalImovel = count($result);

for($i=0;$i<$totalImovel;$i++) {

echo $i."<br>";
echo $result[$i]['Codigo']."<br>";

}
```

Mas não obtenho resultado algum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outra opção para criar um array a partir de outro array usando uma chave como index seria usar a função [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php) do PHP.

```
$lista = array(
    3152=>array('codigo'=>3152),
    3153=>array('codigo'=>3153),
    2448=>array('codigo'=>2448),
    3141=>array('codigo'=>3141),
    3151=>array('codigo'=>3151),
);

$arr2= array_column($lista, 'codigo');
```

Comment: Feito cirurgião, limpo e preciso, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Solução:

```
echo '<pre>';
//print_r( $result );
foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo $item['Codigo'];
    echo '<br>';
}
echo '</pre>';
```

O que pega é que quando você chama o "for" com o índice 0 o objeto não é encontrado, pq o índice está vindo já como "3152", etc. Também você pode pegar o código direto no índice desta forma:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($result as $key => $item) {
    echo 'Código: '. $key;
    echo '<br>';
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Realmente, isso se chama array associativo(algo assim), onde não se usa o índice(começando com 0) e sim uma `key`(no seu caso o codigo) que está ligada ao valor.

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
    $lista = array(
        3152=>array('codigo'=>3152),
        3153=>array('codigo'=>3153),
        2448=>array('codigo'=>2448),
        3141=>array('codigo'=>3141),
        3151=>array('codigo'=>3151),
    );
    $lista2 = array();
    foreach($lista as $chave => $valor){
        array_push($lista2,$valor);
    }

    $jsonObj = json_encode($lista2);
    print_r($jsonObj);
?>
```

Caso não queria trabalhar com o JSON pode utilizar o conteúdo do array `$lista2`

Comment: Ele está retornando o Json de uma API @Murilo, e está transformando o json em um array (json_decode($result, true) --> o parâmetro true transforma o json em array).

Comment: @BrunoRomualdo exatamente, ele recebe um JSON, e transforma em array para tentar tratar como ele disse na pergunta, na minha resposta, além de fazer exatamente o que ele pediu na pergunta, só incluí a opção dele voltar para JSON, qual o problema?

Comment: É mais a questão de transformar em json novamente, não acho que ele queira trazer um json transformar em array e voltar para json novamente.

Comment: @BrunoRomualdo por isso que na minha resposta eu coloquei no final que se ele não quiser usar o Jason pra usar os dados de $lista2

Comment: Vem de Json para Array, não faz sentido repetir o processo, mas obrigado pela sua contribuição.